# Php display random records on radio button [quiz]

Tags: php, mysql, random

I'm doing a simple php quiz game. I have the questions and answers stored in the database. The table structure of my tblQuiz is like this:

```
_id, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, correctanswer.
```

I have to randomly display them on the page.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Quiz</title>
<?php 
include 'db.php';
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT *
      FROM tblquiz ORDER BY rand()" );
      $stmt->execute();
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    $number = 0;
    for($i=0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); $i++){
            $number++;  
            $id = $row['_id'];
            $question = $row['question'];
            $answer1 = $row['answer1'];
            $answer2 = $row['answer2'];
            $answer3 = $row['answer3'];
            $correctanswer = $row['correctanswer'];       
?>

     <h4> <?php echo $number . ".) " . $question; ?></h4>   
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answer1; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $answer1; ?></label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answer2; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $answer2; ?></label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answer3; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $answer3; ?></label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $correctanswer; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $correctanswer; ?></label>

<?php
    }
?>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</body>
</html>
```

But I can't seem to get what I want to achieve, only the questions are being randomly displayed. I also want to randomly position the answers themselves.

Im newbie in PHP so I need your help. Thanks a lot in advance to those who will help.

Comment: Because you're outputting `$answer1`, `$answer2`, `$answer3` in a fixed order...

Comment: @Passerby how do I put them in a random order?

Comment: @Dunkey You have to come up with some mechanism to do so, have you given any thought to how you might do this?

Comment: @Dunkey One way to do it is put the answers (index or actual content) in an array, [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it, and then output accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body>
<?php 
$number = 0;
for($i=0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); $i++){
        $number++;  
        $id = $row['_id'];
        $question = $row['question'];
      $ans_array = array($row['answer1'],$row['answer2'],$row['answer3'],$row['correctanswer']);
     shuffle($ans_array);
?>

 <h4> <?php echo $number . ".) " . $question; ?></h4>   
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[0]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $ans_array[0]; ?></label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[1]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $ans_array[1]; ?></label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[2]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $ans_array[2]; ?></label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[3]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $ans_array[3]; ?></label>

<?php
}
?>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</body>
```

Comment: thank you! This solves my problem. As others say I have to put them into array and shuffle them.

Comment: your welcome :) yes you need to shuffle the answers separately as you want then also to be random.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<?php
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
} 
$firstquarter = array('January', 'February', 'March');
$suff = shuffle_assoc($firstquarter);

foreach($suff as $suffle)
{   
?>
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $suffle; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $suffle; ?></label>

<?php
}
?>
```

**Editor Fiddle** : http://www.phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rgc-zfj

**Result Fiddle** : http://www.phpfiddle.org/api/run/rgc-zfj

**In your code**

```
<body>
<?php 
$number = 0;
for($i=0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); $i++){
        $number++;  
        $id = $row['_id'];
        $question = $row['question'];
      $ans_array = array($row['answer1'],$row['answer2'],$row['answer3'],$row['correctanswer']);
     $suff = shuffle_assoc($ans_array);
     foreach($suff as $suffle)
     {
?>
 <h4> <?php echo $number . ".) " . $question; ?></h4>   
 <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $suffle; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $suffle; ?></label>
 <?php
     }
}
?>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store all your answers in a single array and then iterate the array randomly and print your answer lables because you can not optimize your query to select the columns randomly.