# How to randomize quiz questions and not repeat questions

Tags: android, mysql, arrays, json

So I have a question object

```
public class Question {

    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String picture;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private String option4;
    private String correctAnswer;
}
```

which I parse data to from a MySQL database using JSON format, as seen below

```
   private class AsyncJsonObject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");
            String jsonResult = "";

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HistoryActivity.this, "Downloading Questions","Please Wait....", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            parsedObject = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
            if(parsedObject == null){
                return;
            }


            quizCount = parsedObject.size();
            firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(0);
            mQuestionView.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(firstQuestion.getPicture())
//                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
//                    .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight)
//                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(mImageView);
            mButtonChoice1.setText(firstQuestion.getOption1());
            mButtonChoice2.setText(firstQuestion.getOption2());
            mButtonChoice3.setText(firstQuestion.getOption3());
            mButtonChoice4.setText(firstQuestion.getOption4());
            mAnswer = firstQuestion.getCorrectAnswer();
            mQuestionNumber++;
            num.setText("Question " + mQuestionNumber);
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
    private List<Question> returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

        List<Question> jsonObject = new ArrayList<Question>();
        JSONObject resultObject = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        Question newItemObject = null;

        try {
            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println("Testing the water " + resultObject.toString());
            jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray("questions");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (jsonArray != null) {     // check jsonArray is null?
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;
                try {
                    jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");
                    String question = jsonChildNode.getString("question");
                    String picture = jsonChildNode.getString("picture");
                    String answerOption1 = jsonChildNode.getString("option1");
                    String answerOption2 = jsonChildNode.getString("option2");
                    String answerOption3 = jsonChildNode.getString("option3");
                    String answerOption4 = jsonChildNode.getString("option4");
                    String correctAnswer = jsonChildNode.getString("correct");
                    newItemObject = new Question(id, question, picture, answerOption1, answerOption2, answerOption3, answerOption4, correctAnswer);
                    jsonObject.add(newItemObject);
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }


    private void showNextQuestion() {

        firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);
        mQuestionView.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(firstQuestion.getPicture())
//                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
//                    .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight)
//                    .centerCrop()
                .into(mImageView);
        mButtonChoice1.setText(firstQuestion.getOption1());
        mButtonChoice2.setText(firstQuestion.getOption2());
        mButtonChoice3.setText(firstQuestion.getOption3());
        mButtonChoice4.setText(firstQuestion.getOption4());
        mAnswer = firstQuestion.getCorrectAnswer();

        mQuestionNumber++;

        num.setText("Question " + mQuestionNumber);


   }
```

and as seen here, i am only retrieving 10 question per user game session

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

I'm trying to achieve 3 things

1. Randomize all the 10 questions from the json array
2. If possible randomize the buttons which the options appear as well(so options a,b,c,d doesn't have a constant position)
3. Not show a user a question they have seen before

Please what's the best method to go about this?

I also read I could randomize the data from MySQL directly using `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10`, but also read that isn't best practice for large data, as it would slow the response, so how can I do this in android?

Thanks

Comment: Suggest using the application code to randomize results rather than the database like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178084/php-display-random-records-on-radio-button-quiz)

Comment: Personally, I would revise the schema

Comment: @Strawberry please what do you mean revise the chema?

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you should consider whether there's scope to normalise.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry i'm new to all this, so I don't get what you are saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) After you retrieve the 10 questions in List, you can just shuffle this list to randomize the position of the 10 questions

2) Same for this. You can first add all the choices in a List of string. Then shuffle this list. Then assign this shuffled list to the choices ensuring that all the time different order is followed.

The code for the above two is as below. I haven't tested this. Some debugging may be required but idea wise, it should work :

```
private List<Question> returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

    List<Question> jsonObject = new ArrayList<Question>();
    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    Question newItemObject = null;

    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        System.out.println("Testing the water " + resultObject.toString());
        jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray("questions");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (jsonArray != null) {     // check jsonArray is null?
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;
            try {
                jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");
                String question = jsonChildNode.getString("question");
                String picture = jsonChildNode.getString("picture");

                // The below code will shuffle the choices
                List<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();
                choices.add(jsonChildNode.getString("option1"));
                choices.add(jsonChildNode.getString("option2"));
                choices.add(jsonChildNode.getString("option3"));
                choices.add(jsonChildNode.getString("option4"));
                Collections.shuffle(choices);
                String answerOption1 = choices.get(0);
                String answerOption2 = choices.get(1);
                String answerOption3 = choices.get(2);
                String answerOption4 = choices.get(3);

                String correctAnswer = jsonChildNode.getString("correct"); 

                newItemObject = new Question(id, question, picture, answerOption1, answerOption2, answerOption3, answerOption4, correctAnswer);
                jsonObject.add(newItemObject);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Collections.shuffle(jsonObject); //This will randomize the 10 questions

        return jsonObject;
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

3) For your third question, since you said you have 9 categories, you can do this:
In each of the 9 tables, add a column called "viewedusers". This column will basically store id of users (separated by commas) who has already viewed this specific question (everytime a user views a question, you append that users id in this column for that specific category).

Now, every time, before you populate the 10 questions, you first check if the userid is already there or not, if yes, don't include that question. If in the end, you cannot get 10 questions, you can display the message "out of questions" or whatever.

Comment: Your suggestion for 1 and 2 worked perfectly, thanks, but for 3 I have 9 tables for 9 categories, so the first question in category 1 would have an id of 1, and the first in category 2 would also have an id of 1. so how can I maintain the IDs in this scenario

Comment: Just a question, what happens in a scenario when a specific user (example User A) views all the questions? How do you plan to populate the ten questions then?

Comment: I actually haven't thought that far, I was thinking of displaying a message "No question available"

Comment: Was wondering how to go about my first comment? regarding same ids for diffrent questions

Comment: @Drwho : I have edited my answer for the third one. Sorry i was away for few days. Also, if you think my answer solved your question, you can check it as accepted solution. Thanks